# Update column in database from model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So I have a `User` model and a `Post` model

`Post` belongs to a User

`Post` has a field in the database called `score`

In the `Post` model I have a method called `score` which gives the post a score based on the fields (needs to be done this way):

```
def score
   score = 0

   if self.title.present?
     score += 5
   end
   if self.author.present?
     score += 5
   end
   if self.body.present?
     score += 5
   end

   score

end
```

**The Question:**

There are loads of `Users` and loads of `Posts`. So What I'm trying to do is after the score is worked out, I want to save it to the Post `score` field in the database for each `Post`. The score should be updated if the user updates the `Post`.

I have looked at using `after_update :score!` but don't understand how to apply the logic

Comment: why do you this in model? and not in controller?

Comment: can you show the controller as well?

Comment: how would you do this in the controller, the controller was created with a standard scaffold generator, and i have permitted the score column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks a little like you are trying to re-invent the wheel ActiveRecord provides you.

If you have a database field `score`, then ActiveRecord will automatically provide an `attribute_reader` and `attribute_writer` for `score` and you should not override these unless you have a really really good reason for it, e.g. you need to add some other resources or some serious business logic into it.

There is a way easier way to solve it, by using the `before_save` hook, which will kick in before any `#create` or `#update`:

```
class Post
  attribute_accessible :score # if you have Rails 4.x you can omit this line

  before_save :update_score

  private
  def update_score
    new_score = 0
    self.score = [:title, :author, :body].each do |field|
      new_score += 5 if send(field).present?
    end

    self.score = new_score
  end
```

This way, ActiveRecord will handle the saving for you and your score will always up to date. Additionally `Post#score` will always return the real value currently saved in the database

Comment: really appreciate the help, also thanks for refactoring the code, GREAT!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this
`after_update :score!`

```
def score!
   score = 0

   if self.title.present?
     score += 5
   end
   if self.author.present?
     score += 5
   end
   if self.body.present?
     score += 5
   end

   self.update_column(:score, score)

end
```

This is to be done in your `Post` model.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [update_column](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_column) method. Like:

```
def score
   score = 0

   if self.title.present?
     score += 5
   end
   if self.author.present?
     score += 5
   end
   if self.body.present?
     score += 5
   end

   self.update_column(:score, score)

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the setter method in the Post model

```
attr_accessible :score

  def score=(value)
  score = 0
   if self.title.present?
     score += 5
   end
   if self.author.present?
     score += 5
   end
   if self.body.present?
     score += 5
   end 
    write_attribute(:score, score)
  end
```